# Tab bar Activity in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the tab bar controller which contains 5 fragments. On click a fragment I will be navigated to next page from the fragment but when I click back from the navigated page it is going to main tab bar controller page instead of the fragment page.

Comment: how you are navigating to next page on clicking a tab ?

Comment: What are "fragments"?

Comment: @Abizern i think `viewControllers` are called `fragments` in Android.

Comment: on click of tab bar item there is button on clicking the button it will navigate to the next class and then clicking back button in that class it is getting back to the home controller not the second tab bar item

Comment: Why would you think it would go to the second tab bar? The controller pushes the new view controller and when you go back it takes you to where you were before. What is it that you want to happen?

Comment: Whan you are using `UITabbarController` each tab has its own navigation controller. You can navigate inside each navigation controller of each tab, but you cant navigate between tabs instead of switching between them.